Multiple linear regression on just categorical variables? change ~ C(location)
I am trying to show that a categorical variable doesn't really affect a continuous variable.
I am using statsmodel formula:
sm.ols(formula=change ~ C(location))

but I feel like I have some theoretical missunderstanding as I am under the impression the model is just fitting for one of the locations. Also the number of samples for each location is  not balanced, would that be an issue?
Is it possible to run such a regression without including a categorical variable?

If done right, you should get back $K$ coefficients when you print the output, where $K$ is the number of distinct values of location. Typically, you will have a constant and $K-1$ dummy variable coefficients. The constant corresponds to the expected value for the omitted category. For every other location, the expected value will be the constant plus the coefficient for that location.
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
import pandas as pd

model = sm.ols(formula='change ~ C(location)', data=df).fit()
coefficients = model.params
print(coefficients)

A variable number of observations at each location does not create a problem. All else equal, coefficients for locations with fewer observations will have bigger standard errors and wider confidence intervals, reflecting the higher uncertainty.
You can run the model without the categorical variables like this:
sm.ols(formula='change ~ 1')

This is just a regression on a constant. This restricts the expected change to be the same in every location and is equivalent to calculating the mean of change.

this is a great answer, thank you! do you have a good reference on why OLS is the same as a t-test? I cant really see the relationship

Take a look here.

awesome, thank you so much, can I ask what is the interpretation of the p-value of the intercept term?
say I have 2 locations, A and B, is the intercept modelling the effect of one of the locations?

The constant corresponds to the expected value for the omitted category mean (say location A). The p-value for the constant is from the null that the expected value is zero. For location B, the expected value will be the constant plus the coefficient for B, so the coefficient is the difference between B and A. The p-value for the B coefficient is for the null that this difference is zero.
